# How to remove pesticides and harmful bacteria from fruits and vegetables?

Tags: health, raw, fruitarianism, fruits, vegetables

I'd like to blend some fruits with their peels, however I'm concerns about pesticides and harmful bacteria. I understand I should buy organic, but in case it's not or just to be safe, what methods I should use to get rid of pesticides and harmful bacteria?

I've heard that you can soak it for some time in vinegar, but there are two problems, the juice may smell with vinegar and you can't make a milk shake, because the milk will curdle.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't think this question is really about vegetarianism or veganism.

Comment: I believe it's part of fruitarian lifestyle.

Comment: Fruitarians cannot eat any pesticides or bacteria?  Anyone should want to remove harmful bacteria and pesticides from any food, including vegetarian food.  Is the bar higher for fruitarians?

Comment: Some bacteria can be harmful (like e.coli or salmonella). Last time when I missed adding vinegar to some blended raw veg sauce I was very sick for few days (couldn't even walk), where normally I never get sick, so something awful got in.

Comment: Yes, some bacteria can be harmful, but is there anything vegetarian about this?  Cycling to work is (probably) compatible with a vegetarian lifestyle but that doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: Vegetarians are eating raw vegs on daily basis more than anybody else, so it's relevant how you prepare and eat them healthy.

Comment: I have [raised a question on meta](http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/26/21).

Comment: I think its a valid question, soaking fruits and vegetables in warm water is supposed to help.

Comment: This question has been reopened after [discussion on meta](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/279/1236).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Centre for Science and Environment](http://www.cseindia.org/content/removing-pesticides-fruits-and-vegetables)

> Washing with 2% of salt water will remove most of the contact pesticide residues that normally appear on the surface of the vegetables and fruits ... fruity vegetables like tomatoes, brinjal and okra require two to three washings.

2% is not really salty enough to affect the taste but if you want you can always rinse again in non-salty water after performing the steps above.

Comment: Also note that there are several kinds of pesticides. Contact pesticides are just one type. Systemic ones might be impossible to remove.